# При попытки запушить изменения в GitHub через Android Studio вылетает ошибка

Tags: android, android-studio, git, github, git-push

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст ошибки:

```
    Invocation failed Unexpected end of file from server
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Invocation failed Unexpected end of file from server
            at git4idea.GitAppUtil.sendXmlRequest(GitAppUtil.java:30)
            at git4idea.http.GitAskPassApp.main(GitAskPassApp.java:58)
    
    ...
    
    error: unable to read askpass response from 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2021.2\tmp\intellij-git-askpass-local.sh'
    bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
    error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
    fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory
    12:03:45.579: [SpinnerAndroidKotlin] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false push --progress --porcelain origin refs/heads/main:main
    Invocation failed Unexpected end of file from server
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Invocation failed Unexpected end of file from server
        at git4idea.GitAppUtil.sendXmlRequest(GitAppUtil.java:30)

...

error: unable to read askpass response from 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2021.2\tmp\intellij-git-askpass-local.sh'
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory
12:11:30.176: [SpinnerAndroidKotlin] git -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false push --progress --porcelain origin refs/heads/main:main
����ࠡ�⠭��� �᪫�祭��: System.MissingMethodException: ��⮤ �� ������: "Void Microsoft.AzureRepos.AzureReposHostProvider..ctor(Microsoft.Git.CredentialManager.ICommandContext)".
   � Microsoft.Git.CredentialManager.Program.Main(String[] args)
Invocation failed Unexpected end of file from server
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invocation failed Unexpected end of file from server
```

Пробовал выполнить следующие действия по инструкции из статьи (https://codeutility.org/git-pull-failed-invocation-failed-unexpected-end-of-file-from-server-stack-overflow/):

"Откройте терминал в Android Studio. Нажмите эту команду:

```
git config credential.helper store
```

Он запросит пароль, введите свой пароль. // в моём случае, пароль не запрашивал

Включите «Использовать помощник по учетным данным» в «Настройки» -> «Контроль версий» -> «Git».
После этих двух шагов вы сможете тянуть, толкать, фиксировать."

Comment: А вы используете MS Azure для публикации изменений? Может, дело в нем? И нужно настроить credentials в удаленном репозитории?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147574/fatal-could-not-read-username-for-https-github-com-no-such-file-or-directo как на счет этого варианта тут посмотрите может решение есть

Comment: такая же проблема, хотя в других IDE от того же JetBrains все ок

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ  - это сгенерировать ssh ключи и добавить публичный ключ в гитхаб. После этого проблем возникать не должно. Вот например [инструкция](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/generate-ssh-key-windows-10) для генерации ключей где используется OpenSSH Client от винды. После генерации у вас будет в папке пользователя на винде папка `.ssh` где будет приватный и публичный ключ (видно из названия). Берете публичный ключ и идете в гитхаб где и добавляете его. Для добавления ключа нужно перейти в настройки аккаунта в раздел SSH and GPG keys и там добавить ключ. Вот [инструкция](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) как это делать. Также вам писал в комменте что у вас возможно не тот гит клиент которые все ломает. Перейдите в настройки студии и добавьте путь к гиту который ставился например [отсюда](https://git-scm.com/downloads). Плюс проверьте правильно ли вы указали адрес удаленного репозитория для работы.